# str_replace in array, and append text at the end

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm kind of stuck on this - I'm looking to replace text in an array (easily done via str_replace), but I would also like to append text onto the end of that specific array. For example, my original array is:

Array
(

```
[1] => DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20130712
[2] => DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20130713
[3] => SUMMARY:Vern
[4] => UID:1fb5aa60-ff89-429e-80fd-ad157dc777b8
[5] => LAST-MODIFIED:20130711T010042Z
[6] => SEQUENCE:1374767972
```

)

I would like to search that array for ";VALUE=DATE" and replace it with nothing (""), but would also like to insert a text string 7 characters after each replace ("T000000"). So my resulting array would be:

Array
(

```
[1] => DTSTART:20130712T000000
[2] => DTEND:20130713T000000
[3] => SUMMARY:Vern
[4] => UID:1fb5aa60-ff89-429e-80fd-ad157dc777b8
[5] => LAST-MODIFIED:20130711T010042Z
[6] => SEQUENCE:1374767972
```

)

Is something like this possible using combinations of str_replace, substr_replace, etc? I'm fairly new to PHP and would love if someone could point me in the right direction! Thanks much

Comment: Yes, I'm bringing iCal events into my site, and any "all day" events not in the "date-time" format trips it up. For example, these events are coming in as all-day "date" values, so I just need to convert them to date-time and it works much easier. It's a dirty way of doing it, but I just needed a quick solution, and can come back later and troubleshoot a bit further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) as an one-stop shop for this type of manipulation:

```
$array = preg_replace('/(.*);VALUE=DATE(.*)/', '$1$2T000000', $array);
```

The regular expression matches any string that contains `;VALUE=DATE` and captures whatever precedes and follows it into capturing groups (referred to as $1 and $2 in the replacement pattern). It then replaces that string with $1 concatenated to $2 (effectively removing the search target) and appends `"T000000"` to the result.

Comment: @EJK - If it worked for you, please click the check mark to the left of his answer to accept it.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using this site. But I must say, this is the fastest and best response I've ever had from a community site before - Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The naive approach would be to loop over each element and check for `;VALUE=DATE`. If it exists, remove it and append `T000000`.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  if (strpos($value, ';VALUE=DATE') !== false) {
    $array[$key] = str_replace(";VALUE=DATE", "", $value) . "T000000";
  }
}
```

Comment: It will concat "T000000" to each position in the array, and no after each replace...

Comment: Oh, srry, I got confused your answer with the Bad Wolf's answer.

Comment: Lol. I spend a lot of minutes wrttting my answer, when I post it, had several similar answers. greetings!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct `str_replace()` is the function that you are looking for. In addition you can use the concatenation operator `.` to append your string to the end of the new string. Is this what you are looking for?

```
$array[1] = str_replace(";VALUE=DATE", "", $array[1])."T000000";
$array[2] = str_replace(";VALUE=DATE", "", $array[2])."T000000";
```

Comment: - This is will append, even if it doesn't replace.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
   if(strpos($array[$i], ";VALUE=DATE")){//look for the text into the string
      //Text found, let's replace and append
      $array[$i]=str_replace(";VALUE=DATE","",$array[$i]);
      $array[$i].="T000000";
   }
   else{
      //text not found in that position, will not replace
      //Do something
   }
}
```

If you want just to replace, just do it

```
$array=str_replace($array,";VALUE=DATE","");
```

And will replace all the text in all the array's positions...